# How can I loop an array in the inline style in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, inline-styles

Here is the partial code:

```
let entries = Object.entries(customStyles);
       <div
        style={[...this.entries].map((item, i) => {
          return item[0] + ': ' + item[1] + ',';
        })}
        onClick={() => this.toggleDropdown(toggled)}
      >
        {selected.label}
      </div>
```

My question is:
customStyles is an object such as

```
customStyles: {
    background: '#14c944',
    color: '#1231e0',
  }
```

I converted the object to an array first and I want to use a map to loop the array in the inline style. But this way doesn't work. 
How can I loop an array in the inline style in jsx?

Comment: what's *'inline style'*?

Comment: Why would you need to translate `customStyles` into array of strings? `style={{..customStyles}}` will perfectly apply your styles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would do that, but if it is important for your project you could try save the loop in a variable and aply `Object.fromEntries` inside the `style property`.

Like this:

```
let entries = Object.entries(customStyles).map((item, i) => {
        return [item[0], item[1]];
    })  

    return (
        <div>
            <p style={Object.fromEntries(entries)}>Example</p>            
        </div>
    );
```

But if this loop is not crucial you could style your elements inside the `style property`.

```
return (
        <div>
            <p style={{background: '#14c944', color: '#1231e0'}}>Example</p>          
        </div>
    );
```

Or just use the `spread operator`:

```
const customStyles = {
        background: '#14c944',
        color: '#1231e0',
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{...customStyles}}>Example</p>           
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: It's really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in Jsx you can use object inside style={}, for Example:

```
<div style={{ height: '100px' }}>My Div</div>
```

but if you need to do this anyway, you can do it like this.

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/niko20/pen/OJPKMmq)

but this is unnecessary since you can do it in the way mentioned above

My English is not very good, I'm sorry, I hope helped you